# Angular 5 ngHide, ngShow, and [hidden] not working

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to make my Angular 5 app hide elements (or show hidden). However, this seems to not work.

I've tried using `ngHide`, `ng-hide`, `ngShow`, `ng-show`, and `[hidden]` — none of them works.

My `login.component.ts` looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  isHidden: boolean = true;
  input_pw: string = 'password';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.isHidden); //console shows true
  }

}
```

And `login.component.html`:

```html
<div class="container">
    
<div class="cont-login">
  <div class="login-pane">

    <div>
      <p class="inner log-labels">Your password</p>
      <input class="txt" type="password" [(ngModel)]="input_pw" ngHide="isHidden">
    </div>

    <div>
      <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Login">
    </div>

  </div>


</div>

</div>
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

NOTE: I did not change or add anything related to CSS.

Comment: if you are using angular 5 like you say, the attribute you need is `[hidden]="isHidden"`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**2019 Update:** I realize that this is somewhat bad advice. As the first comment states, this heavily depends on the situation, and it is **not** a bad practice to use the [hidden] attribute: see the comments for some of the cases where you need to use it and not `*ngIf`

**Original answer:**

You should always try to use `*ngIf` instead of `[hidden]`.

```
 <input *ngIf="!isHidden" class="txt" type="password" [(ngModel)]="input_pw" >
```

There are several [blog posts about](http://www.talkingdotnet.com/dont-use-hidden-attribute-angularjs-2/) that topics, but the bottom line is, that Hidden usually means you do not want the browser to render the object - using angular you still waste resource on rendering it, and it will end up in the DOM anyway (and tricky users can see it with basic browser manipulation).

Comment: It depends on the case. With *ngIf, you actually add or remove elements from the DOM, which is a lot more process then just hidding or showing an element.

Comment: May I ask, why, in this case, ngShow and ngHide do not work? Or is this a problem with angular itself?

Comment: ngShow and ngHide is AngularJS sytnax, which is totally different from Angular2+

Comment: And to elaborate further on the subject: I still vote for `*ngIf`.
If you remove or add single object to the DOM tree, the rendering will be unnoticeable. But if you do not remove elements, just turn off their visibility (which is done by adding hidden:true style by angular) you will stack them up in your DOM: all the component copies, references, bindings, detectors etc. and will considerably slow down the overall performance. ([Source](http://www.codelord.net/2015/07/28/angular-performance-ng-show-vs-ng-if/) )

Comment: Late to the party, but there are cases where hiding something is NEEDED. For instance, with material, the mat-table pagination will NOT WORK if you use *ngIf to toggle whether or not you see it on the screen.

Comment: To support the other comments: there are some use cases when hidden is needed, and preferred over a ngIf - The "should always use ngIf" is inaccurate and really depends on the scenario.

Comment: ngif to hide a mat-table column doesn't work since the id (in the .ts) expects it to be in the dom.

Answer (score 55):

If you want to just toggle visibility and still keep the input in DOM:

```html
<input class="txt" type="password" [(ngModel)]="input_pw" 
     [style.visibility]="isHidden? 'hidden': 'visible'">
```

The other way around is as per [answer by @rrd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49669746/11917891), which is to use HTML `hidden` attribute. If the `hidden` attribute on an HTML element is set to `true`, browsers are supposed to hide the element from display, but the problem is that this behavior is overridden if the element has an explicit `display` style mentioned.

```css
.hasDisplay {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input class="hasDisplay" hidden value="shown" />
<input hidden value="not shown">
```

To overcome this, you can opt to use an explicit CSS rule for `[hidden]` that overrides the display:

```css
[hidden] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Yet another way is to have a `is-hidden` class and do:

```html
<input [class.is-hidden]="isHidden"/>
```

```css
.is-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

*If you use `display: none`, the element will be skipped from the static flow and no space will be allocated for it. If you use `visibility: hidden`, it will be included in the flow and a space will be allocated but it will be blank space.*

The important thing is to use one way across an application rather than mixing different ways thereby making the code less maintainable.

If you want to remove it from DOM:

```html
<input class="txt" type="password" [(ngModel)]="input_pw" *ngIf="!isHidden">
```

Comment: This is the best way, cross-browser, to accomplish OPs question.

Comment: Should definitely be the accepted answer. using ngIf is not preferable to hidden depending on the use case scenario.

Comment: `[style.display]="isHidden? 'none': 'block'"` - this worked well - ngIf was not working at all - thanks!

Comment: @SliverNinja-MSFT I have updated the answer to explain things further as I see more people are interested.

Comment: Thank you. I would not think of the display property.

Answer (score 44):

The `[hidden]` attribute will work but you need to check the CSS:

```html
<input class="txt" type="password" [(ngModel)]="input_pw" [hidden]="isHidden" />
```

```css
[hidden] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

That should work as you want.

Comment: you shouldnt need to check the css as it _should_ work with just the `[hidden]="isHidden"`

Comment: Worked for me without the CSS.  This seems like the best answer if you genuinely do want the element to remain in the DOM, but not be seen.

Comment: @mast3rd3mon it worked for me. Why does this work though? How is the default [hidden] behavior not working correctly.

Comment: @WilliamHampshire did you set it to a variable? `[hidden]="isHidden"`? if so, did you set your equivalent of `isHidden` to a `true` value?

Comment: This works for me thank you, is important know that styles set up in component to hide!!

Comment: `[hidden]` adds a very weak selector on that element. it can be easily overridden by another display rule. That's why you need `!important`.

Comment: I needed the CSS on our project as we have a dependency on a UI framework whose latest version introduced the display: block change which broke our code - hence the override which worked.

Answer (score 5):

If you cannot use `*ngIf`, `[class.hide]` works in Angular 7.

```html
<mat-select (selectionChange)="changeFilter($event.value)" 
            multiple 
            [(ngModel)]="selected">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let filter of gridOptions.columnDefs"
              [class.hide]="filter.headerName=='Action'"  
              [value]="filter.field">
   {{ filter.headerName }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add `[hidden]="true"` to a `div`, the actual thing that happens is that a class `[hidden]` is added to this element conditionally with `display: none`.

Please check the styles of the element in the browser to ensure that no other style is affecting the `display` property of the element like this:

[image]

If you find that the `display` of `[hidden]` class is overridden, you need to add this CSS rule to your styles:

```css
[hidden] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: that solved my issue. My css for the DIV had "display: flex" and I was then setting [hidden]="someCondition", not realising display was overriding hidden. I seperated this into 2 DIVs and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use `[style.visibility]="isHidden ? 'hidden': 'visible'"`. This will hide your element, but it will still take the same space in DOM and affect a page layout.
2. Another option is using `[hidden]="condition"` in your templates. This will add `[hidden]` attribute to the element. A browser will apply `display: hidden` to this element only if there's no `display` property set explicitly in your CSS for this element (by id, element's class or element's tag etc.) Otherwise, you should set the following to completely hide the element which will no longer take space in your layout:

```css
[hidden] {
    display: none !important;
}
```

3. Also, you can conditionally set class on the element `[class.is-hidden]="condition"`. Then in your CSS, in class `.is-hidden` you can use any CSS rules you want:

```css
.is-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

or

```css
.is-hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Or, for an accessible and layout-friendly alternative to `display: none` (not readable by screen readers) and `visibility: hidden` (takes up physical space in the DOM) ([source](https://github.com/30-seconds/30-seconds-of-css/blob/master/snippets/offscreen.md)):

```css
.is-hidden {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, `[hidden]="true"` was being overridden by `d-flex` on the `div` element.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways for hiding an element:

1. Use the `hidden` HTML attribute. In Angular, you can bind it with one or more fields like this:

```html
<input class="txt" type="password" [(ngModel)]="input_pw" [hidden]="isHidden">
```

2. Better way of doing this is to use `*ngIf` directive like this:

```html
<input class="txt" type="password" [(ngModel)]="input_pw" *ngIf="!isHidden">
```

This is a better way because it doesn't just hide the element, it removes it from the HTML code, so this will help your page to render.

Comment: Example number 2 is the same as 1. Directive ngIf doesnt good, because remove input from DOM.

Comment: @bluray edited . why do you think it shouldn't remove it from DOM ?

Comment: It depend on the case. For example if you used it `@ViewChild` and it would be removed from DOM, viewchild would be undefined. It would be a problem. Moreover, DOM operation are very expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<input class="txt" type="password" [(ngModel)]="input_pw" [hidden]="isHidden">
```

Comment: Tried that - still nothing. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<button (click)="click()">Click me</button>

<input class="txt" type="password" [(ngModel)]="input_pw" [ngClass]="{'hidden': isHidden}" />
```

**component.ts:**

```
isHidden: boolean = false;
click(){
    this.isHidden = !this.isHidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`[class.cdk-visually-hidden]=true` is working for angular 14

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent an element from being rendered, since Angular 17, you can use [built-in control flow](https://angular.dev/guide/templates/control-flow), an alternative template syntax for conditionally showing or hiding elements. In your case, the syntax looks like the following:

```html
@if (isHidden) {
  <input class="txt" type="password" [(ngModel)]="input_pw">
}
```

> As of Angular 17, control flow is in developer preview and may change before becoming stable.

If you want the element to be rendered but not visible, check the other answers.