# How can I hide DOM element using [hidden] property although we use display css property?

Tags: html, css, angular

```js
    public hide(){
        this.show = !this.show;
    }
```

```css
    .h1{
         display: flex;
     }
```

```html
    <button (click)="hide()">Hide/Show</button>

      <h1 class="h1" [hidden]="!show">

        Hide me!
      </h1>
```

Here is the Problem. I have set a function for hide the DOM element. So If I click the button text will be hide. Its OK. but problem is I want to use `display: flex;` if I use this CSS property hide is not working. If I remove `display` css property definitely text will be hide

1. I want to hide the text using `[hidden]=""`
2. I want to use `display:flex`

using this both how can I hide the text , Have a any way to do this ? If not why ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=angular+set+hidden+attribute+site:stackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: [Likely dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49669654/angular-5-nghide-ngshow-hidden-not-working)

Comment: you can use "style": `[style.display]="!show?'none':null"`, so, if "show=false" style.display=none, else there're no attribute style.display

Comment: Yes, But why can't i use [hidden]="" & display:flex. both

Answer (score 1):

In your css:

```css
h1 {
  display: flex;
}

h1[hidden] {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: yes , but why cant bind [hidden]="" to DOM and use display property?

Comment: This likely means that your CSS rule for the `h1` setting the `display` property comes AFTER the `[hidden]` css rule. CSS will always apply rules that appear later with a higher priority. Hence Cascading Style Sheets.