# What's the problem with [hidden] property in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm using the Angular project and I want to hide a div when the value of a boolean varaible is loading = true.
I assign the variable to false at the beginning,

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   this.loading = false;
 
}
```

However, the div always is shown even the variable is false, not true

```
        <div [hidden]="loading" id="loding_div">
       
        {{loading}}
        Loading the div...
                  
        </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 5 ngHide ngShow \[hidden\] not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49669654/angular-5-nghide-ngshow-hidden-not-working)

Comment: not, I'm doing the same way

Comment: If you want it to be hidden the value should be true

Comment: This div will be hidden when `loading === true`, and `shown` when `false`. Do you by any chance have `ChangeDetection` set to `OnPush` for this component? If so, could be that you need to run a cd check manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can [disabled] instead of[hidden] to hide the div.

```html
<div [disabled]="loading" id="loding_div">
       
        {{loading}}
        Loading the div...
                  
</div>
```